# How Do You Find $K_\beta$ X-Ray Energy?

Tags: atomic-physics, x-rays

I know you can use Moseley's law to calculate $K_\alpha$ X-ray energy. Can this law be used to calculate the $K_\beta$ energy?

$$
\Delta E = (-13.6eV)(Z-1)^2\left(\frac{1}{n_{1}^2}-\frac{1}{n_{2}^2}\right)
$$

I saw on http://minerva.union.edu/labrakes/PIXE_Physics100_Lecture3_F14.pdf that they use it to calculate the $K_\beta$ wavelength for copper, but this doesn't make sense to me. How could it still be $Z-1$? Isn't there more screening/shielding because the electron is coming from the $M$ shell?